# Unable to disable TLS v1.0 with play-mailer 5.0 (using Play 2.5.x)

Tags: security, playframework, java-security

I disabled TLS version on my Play web server (2.5.x + Scala) using java.security (using Java 8) file as below:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, \
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC
```

With this change (TLSv1) I am not able to send emails to smtp.gmail.com:465. I am using play-mailer version 5.0.0. The settings in application.conf file:

```
host = smtp.gmail.com
port = 465
ssl = yes
```

I get following error:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2055)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer$$anon$2.send(MailerPlugin.scala:100)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1351)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:543)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:348)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. Ref: [https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/issues/150](http://here%20(play-mailer))

Briefly: configure ssl protocols via System properties.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the expected behavior. You are getting an exception that the protocol is disabled. What behavior did you expect?

Comment: It should use TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2 when establishing TLS connection with smtp.gmail.com server. Why it should use only TLSv1.0 which is anyways deprecated because of security vulnerability ?